# docker not installing requirements on docker

Tags: python, docker, pip

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install
RUN apt install python3.9 -y
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN git clone https://ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/username/repo

WORKDIR ./appy/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3.9", "main.py"]
```

Hey, for some reason I'm getings

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/appy/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import disnake
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'disnake'
```

requirements.txt

```
disnake=2.4.0
psutil=5.8.0
motor=2.5.1
aiohttp=3.7.4.post0
```

It appears that the packages in `requirements.txt` are not being installed properly. Any suggestions to what could be causing this? when building the container there doesn't seem to be any errors.And I can visually see when the container is built that all packages are installed. Including `disnake`.

Comment: What base image are you using? Your posted Dockerfile is missing the `FROM` line...

Comment: Apologies, I am using ubuntu:latest

Comment: Does `pip` go with `python3.9` in this setup?  Do you need an explicit `pip3` instead of `pip`?  Could use start the image `FROM python:3.9` instead of manually installing Python?

Comment: Thank you very much, this resolved the problems!

Comment: If David's comment re `pip` with `python3.9` resolved the issue, then another possible solution could be to replace `run pip...` with `run python3.9 -m pip install -r...`